# Solve for $x$ and $y$ : $3x^{\log 3}=4y^{\log 4}$, $4^{\log x}=3^{\log y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

My try: By using the above information we can form two equations
\begin{align}
(\log 3)(\log 3x) &= (\log 4)(\log 4y) \text{ and}\\
(\log x)(\log 4) &= (\log y)(\log 3).
\end{align}

But they become too difficult to solve.

I need your help. Any hint or another method to solve this.

Comment: now solve simultaneously. this is jee 2012 question.

Comment: Use the fact that $\log ab = \log a+\log b$ if $a>0, b>0$. And then substitute $u=\log x$, $v=\log y$ to obtain the linear system

Comment: @VasilyMitch I got the answer but it is still lengthy , is there any other way to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your first transformed equation is wrong:
$$
2x^n = 2(x^n)\neq(2x)^n,
$$

So the right logarithming gives:
$$
(\log 3)(\log x) + \log 3 = (\log 4)(\log y) + \log 4
$$

If $u=\log x$, $v=\log y$, $a=\log 3$, $b=log 4$, then:

$$
 au+a = bv+b,\\
 bu = av
$$

Multiply first one by $ab$ and let $t=bu=av$:
$$
a^2(bu)+a^2b = b^2(av)+ab^2,\\
(b^2-a^2)t = -ab(b-a),\\
(a+b)t = -ab,\\
t=-\frac{ab}{a+b}
$$

From that we get $u = -\frac{b}{a+b}$, $v=-\frac{a}{a+b}$. After that you can substitute for $x,y$ back.